# Property (retain) object being released without ever being flagged for release

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm at my wits end.  I'm trying to debug a crash, and finally I manage to track it down.  My 'minutesLeft' variable is somehow being released.

Problem is, I never set it to release, and the property is set to retain.  I can't figure out what is going on!

Using the zombie variable, I got the following message:
    *** -[CFNumber intValue]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x728fdd0

and tracked it down to the following line of code:

```
NSLog(@"MeterViewController minutesLeft %i", [minutesLeft intValue]);
```

The problem is when I declare the property...
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *minutesLeft;
So the property should be handling the retain for me!

The value is set using...

```
minutesLeft=[NSNumber numberWithInt:row];
```

and...

```
minutesLeft=[NSNumber numberWithInt:(((timeLeft)/60)%60)];
```

For dealloc and viewDidUnload I have

```
self.minutesLeft=nil;
```

but since I'm not leaving the view, those shouldn't be effecting anything.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting the local variable that is the backing for the property, not the property itself. Thus it doesn't get retained. Try:

```
self.minutesLeft = [NSNumber numberWithInt:row]
```

or

```
self.minutesLeft = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(((timeLeft)/60)%60)];
```

(Note the `self.`)

You are doing it correctly when deallocating though (setting `self.minutesLeft = nil`).

Comment: Doesn't it just figure that the code written by someone else would be the code doing it right.  I thought the two were synonymous :(